# tweets are not saved to my device and no error is given

Tags: python, json, twitter, save, twitterapi-python

I am trying to save tweets with specific hashtag to JSON file, the code is not giving me any error. however, data is not saved and I can not find the file on my device.

I have another question, how can I maximize the number of tweets saved in 2 days ?

looking for your support,
thank you

```
# import tweepy library to access Twitter REST APIs service
import tweepy

#Python code to get twitter access
#Authorize access to Twitter using access keys & tokens from my developer account using tweepy OAuthHandler method
from tweepy import OAuthHandler 
import tweepy as tw
consumer_key=''
consumer_secret=''
access_token=''
access_token_secret=''
#online authuntication 
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth) #The api variable is now our entry point for most of the operations we can perform with Twitter.

#import JSON 
import json
query='#vaccine' # define the query of our search
def process_or_store(tweet): #define process or store function to save the tweets with #vaccine to JSON local file 
    #open local file names (vaccinetweets)
    with open('vaccinetweets.json','w') as outfile:
        #write the tweets to the saved file and make it in beatiful print mode
        json.dump(tweet._json,file,sort_keys = True,indent = 4)  
    # mt.write(json.dumps(tweet)+'\n') #write the tweets to the saved file and insert a line between the tweets 
        #with the for loop use the cursor interface to navigate through tweets meeting our search criteria
        for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=query,lang="en",since='2021-04-01').items():
            process_or_store(tweet._json) #save the tweets
```

Comment: you haven't called the function

Comment: Also, in the line `json.dump(tweet._json,file,sort_keys = True,indent = 4)`, you might want to try replacing `file` with `outfile`.

Comment: Thank you for your response :), I have tried to replace the file with outfile but it did not work.
Am still at the beginning of my learning process so can you please guide me on how to write the code to call the function?
Thank you so much